# How to get information about a package before installation in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I was wondering how to get the information about a package in the terminal, before installation with `apt install` so that I can decide whether to install it, based on the description.

Thanks!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use

```
 apt-cache show PACKAGE
```

to see the description and some other information about package after its installed

```
 dpkg -L package_name
```

to see what files the package contains.

Comment: The second hint with listing the package content ie. files doesn't work for me.  It always says `dpkg-query: package 'package_name' is not installed` so it can't be used for inspecting the file before installing it.  The `apt-file` utility seems to be a more viable option for that, although I can't refer from my own experience yet.

Comment: dpkg -L won't always work for example aide-xen will report not installed.

Answer (score 14):

For similar tasks, the APT (the Advanced Package Tool) package management system provides several solutions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool).

---

```
apt-cache showpkg *package_name*
```

Description taken from here https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-cache

> showpkg displays information about the packages listed on the command
> line. Remaining arguments are package names. The available versions
> and reverse
> dependencies of each package listed are listed, as well as forward dependencies for each version. Forward (normal) dependencies
> are those packages upon
> which the package in question depends; reverse dependencies are those packages that depend upon the package in question. Thus,
> forward dependencies must
> be satisfied for a package, but reverse dependencies need not be. For instance, apt-cache showpkg libreadline2 would produce
> output similar to the
> following

```
$ apt-cache showpkg javacc
Package: javacc
Versions: 
5.0-5 (/var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.ru.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/apt/lists/httpredir.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-am)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.ru.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 61505d89a764133cbd782b370c93fe98
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.ru.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: 61505d89a764133cbd782b370c93fe98


Reverse Depends: 
  ant-optional,javacc
  ant-optional,javacc
  libjavacc-maven-plugin-java,javacc
  javacc-doc,javacc
  ant-optional,javacc
Dependencies: 
5.0-5 - default-jre-headless (16 (null)) java1-runtime-headless (16 (null)) java2-runtime-headless (0 (null)) javacc-doc (0 (null)) 
Provides: 
5.0-5 - 
Reverse Provides:
```

**apt-cache show *package_name***

> Displays the package records for the named packages.

```
$ apt-cache show javacc
Package: javacc
Version: 5.0-5
Installed-Size: 380
Maintainer: Debian Java Maintainers <pkg-java-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Depends: default-jre-headless | java1-runtime-headless | java2-runtime-headless
Suggests: javacc-doc
Description-en: Parser generator for use with Java
 Java Compiler-Compiler (JavaCC) is (according to sun)
 "the most popular parser generator" for use with Java [tm]
 applications.
 .
 A parser generator is a tool that reads a grammar specification
 and converts it to a Java program that can recognize matches to
 the grammar. In addition to the parser generator itself, JavaCC
 provides other standard capabilities related to parser
 generation such as tree building (via a tool called JJTree
 included with JavaCC), actions, debugging, etc.
Description-md5: 61505d89a764133cbd782b370c93fe98
Homepage: http://javacc.java.net
Tag: devel::code-generator, devel::lang:java, implemented-in::java,
 interface::commandline, role::program, scope::utility
Section: java
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/j/javacc/javacc_5.0-5_all.deb
Size: 284722
MD5sum: b1efd2defeba45cd97a48541235e6255
SHA1: c5e4b1991be06ec56e6d1a5b916c714068e5bf6b
SHA256: 757f9566d488858285c23c2ac12e05168af38953cf034f6e44123c2a88cb7c83
```

**apt-cache policy *package_name***

> This is meant to help debug issues relating to the preferences file.
> With no arguments it will print out the priorities of each source.
> Otherwise it prints out detailed information about the priority
> selection of the named package.

```
$ apt-cache policy javacc
javacc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0-5
  Version table:
     5.0-5 0
        500 http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

**apt-cache madison *package_name***

> apt-cache's madison command attempts to mimic the output format and
> a subset of the functionality of the Debian archive management
> tool, madison. It displays available versions of a package in a
> tabular format. Unlike the original madison, it can only display
> information for the architecture for which APT has retrieved
> package lists (APT::Architecture).

```
$ apt-cache madison javacc
    javacc |      5.0-5 | http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
    javacc |      5.0-5 | http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
    javacc |      5.0-5 | http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main Sources
```

**apt-cache showsrc *package_name***

> Displays all the source package records that match the given package
> names. All versions are shown, as well as all records that declare the
> name to be a Binary.

```
$ apt-cache showsrc javacc
Package: javacc
Binary: javacc, javacc-doc
Version: 5.0-5
Maintainer: Debian Java Maintainers <pkg-java-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Uploaders: Emmanuel Bourg <ebourg@apache.org>
Build-Depends: ant, debhelper (>= 7), cdbs (>= 0.4.5.3), default-jdk
Build-Depends-Indep: ant-optional, libxalan2-java, docbook-to-man, junit, maven-repo-helper
Architecture: all
Standards-Version: 3.9.4
Format: 3.0 (quilt)
Files:
 6715506605c7a4e750309b7ef645ec86 1397 javacc_5.0-5.dsc
 edf47d357c6f36458474a1b537b88a12 711183 javacc_5.0.orig.tar.gz
 b3308a9aefeca4318a0838b2a3213cea 7893 javacc_5.0-5.debian.tar.gz
Vcs-Browser: http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/pkg-java/trunk/javacc
Vcs-Svn: svn://anonscm.debian.org/pkg-java/trunk/javacc
Checksums-Sha1:
 f4a4ea175ce87af588c713eaab8caeaefc64183f 1397 javacc_5.0-5.dsc
 f6e12a183579a67528f351282251560faf4737db 711183 javacc_5.0.orig.tar.gz
 4aebf3cadecd96f304f80786f07473574569dc02 7893 javacc_5.0-5.debian.tar.gz
Checksums-Sha256:
 4a61f89f984809964e3d63d159998ff29c951765a046ac87dca32b21eb54f99b 1397 javacc_5.0-5.dsc
 aab2c3e2f37648b9e708e6bad4c8b544cba63b66f1791907e6e3f89609b27150 711183 javacc_5.0.orig.tar.gz
 66418d91dc6c6d45d941181d08150d272d3db57a944f3ce61847e5e1ec7c0659 7893 javacc_5.0-5.debian.tar.gz
Homepage: http://javacc.java.net
Package-List: 
 javacc deb java optional
 javacc-doc deb doc optional
Directory: pool/main/j/javacc
Priority: source
Section: java
```

**apt-cache depends *package_name***

> Shows a listing of each dependency a package has and all the possible
> other packages that can fulfill that dependency.

```
$ apt-cache depends javacc
javacc
 |Depends: default-jre-headless
 |Depends: <java1-runtime-headless>
    gcj-4.8-jre-headless
    gcj-4.9-jre-headless
    gcj-jre-headless
  Depends: <java2-runtime-headless>
    default-jre-headless
    gcj-4.8-jre-headless
    gcj-4.9-jre-headless
    gcj-jre-headless
    openjdk-7-jre-headless
    openjdk-8-jre-headless
  Suggests: javacc-doc
```

---

**Testing environment**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
setivolkylany$/media/setivolkylany/WorkDisk/Private$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Based on https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-cache and  http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/apt-cache.8.html

Answer (score 0):

For those just looking for a basic summary of the package :

```
apt-cache search ^package-name$
```