# How to inspect and validate a deb package before installation?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I want to know as much as possible about a `.deb` package before I install it. There is a significant amount of metadata generated during regular package building and I know that there are also signed packages like the ones from the distribution repositories.

[This is not the answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/47856/40581) I'm looking for. Of course I can open the package with file-roller and find the build date this way, but I want to go beyond that. I think of something comparable to how you check TLS certificates in Firefox.

Key questions:

- When was the package built?
- If possible by whom or where was the package built?
- What are the dependencies? (Link to good answer for completeness.)
- Is the package signed?

  - Who or what signed it?

Regarding the last point, I know about `.dsc` files, though these are usually not offered on 3rd party sites. (May be we should raise awareness here so that this will change in the future.)

You can use google-chrome as an example for 3rd party packages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normal deb files do not contain all data you need, except that you can get by `dpkg-deb --info` or look into `DEBIAN/control` file.

You can have dsc files with this data, if you download from launchpad or official repositories.

Deb files are not signed by default. General recommendation is not to install deb packages from sites you do not trust.

There are no special security instruments in Debian packages.

Answer (score 28):

Use this:

```
dpkg-deb --info <deb file>
```

Prefer to use apt if you need them to be signed.

Comment: works like a charm

Answer (score 10):

All you should need is

```
dpkg -I package.deb
```

Here is sample out put of a package named `hostapd_2.1-0ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb` on my PC

```
 ~$ dpkg -I '/home/mark/hostapd_2.1-0ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb' 
 new debian package, version 2.0.
 size 422472 bytes: control archive=2619 bytes.
      66 bytes,     3 lines      conffiles            
    1537 bytes,    31 lines      control              
    1085 bytes,    15 lines      md5sums              
    1375 bytes,    53 lines   *  postinst             #!/bin/sh
     359 bytes,    14 lines   *  postrm               #!/bin/sh
     570 bytes,    30 lines   *  preinst              #!/bin/sh
     204 bytes,     7 lines   *  prerm                #!/bin/sh
 Package: hostapd
 Source: wpa (2.1-0ubuntu1.2)
 Version: 1:2.1-0ubuntu1.2
 Architecture: amd64
 Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
 Installed-Size: 1219
 Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libnl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7), libnl-genl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1), lsb-base (>= 3.2-13), initscripts (>= 2.88dsf-13.3)
 Section: net
 Priority: optional
 Multi-Arch: foreign
 Homepage: http://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/
 Description: user space IEEE 802.11 AP and IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP Authenticator
  Originally, hostapd was an optional user space component for Host AP
  driver. It adds more features to the basic IEEE 802.11 management
  included in the kernel driver: using external RADIUS authentication
  server for MAC address based access control, IEEE 802.1X Authenticator
  and dynamic WEP keying, RADIUS accounting, WPA/WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i/RSN)
  Authenticator and dynamic TKIP/CCMP keying.
  .
  The current version includes support for other drivers, an integrated
  EAP authenticator (i.e., allow full authentication without requiring
  an external RADIUS authentication server), and RADIUS authentication
  server for EAP authentication.
  .
  hostapd works with the following drivers:
  .
   * mac80211 based drivers with support for master mode [linux]
   * Host AP driver for Prism2/2.5/3 [linux]
   * Driver interface for FreeBSD net80211 layer [kfreebsd]
   * Any wired Ethernet driver for wired IEEE 802.1X authentication.
 Original-Maintainer: Debian/Ubuntu wpasupplicant Maintainers <pkg-wpa-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
```

And another at random called `pulseaudio_6.0-90-g75dd2-1_amd64.deb`

```
~$ dpkg -I '/home/mark/pulseaudio/pulseaudio_6.0-90-g75dd2-1_amd64.deb' 
 new debian package, version 2.0.
 size 1421422 bytes: control archive=314 bytes.
       0 bytes,     0 lines      conffiles            
     222 bytes,     9 lines      control              
 Package: pulseaudio
 Priority: extra
 Section: checkinstall
 Installed-Size: 8144
 Maintainer: root@Ubuntu
 Architecture: amd64
 Version: 6.0-90-g75dd2-1
 Provides: pulseaudio
 Description: Package created with checkinstall 1.6.2
```

Comment: So when was this package built or made available?

Answer (score 4):

For packages available through configured repositories, try:

`apt-cache show <package-name>`

You'll get a lot of metadata (Maintainer, Original Maintainer, Depends, MD5) but maybe not all you're looking for.

Comment: Please read carefully: ***before*** installation

Comment: This is applicable only to repositories.

Answer (score 2):

I want to give a GUI based desktop user friendly solution. I am using Ubuntu Mate 18.04

1. Double click the .deb file. It Will open in Gdebi. If it is not already installed you can install Gdebi using `sudo apt-get install gdebi`.

   [image]
2. When you Double click the .deb file, you can find the Package Name, Dependencies, Which Files it will install and where and much more.
3. If you decide to install the package use `Install Package`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to **verify integrity** is to confirm with other testimonials that your SHA256 is the expected SHA256.

A *git* **with a minimal community controlling it**, [is like a blockchain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46195087/287948), so is a reliable source to verify integrity, and is impossible to do the [Man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) in all  clones of the community.

### Some curate list of SHA256 results?

We can start a Github repository with a simple CSV integrity checks, but you need to trust the CSV maintaining community, at least.

For example `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`

1. `dpkg-deb --info google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` say *"... size 103884100 bytes: control archive=15708 bytes (...) Package: google-chrome-stable (...) Version: 119.0.6045.159-1"*
2. `sha256sum google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` say *"c409bb6cfb279c90fb516353b4728cbf97a71e8deb33dc3433cd503ea65594fe"*.

So, the CSV look like

```
file,size,size_cntrl,package,version
google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb,103884100,15708,c409bb6cfb279c90fb516353b4728cbf97a71e8deb33dc3433cd503ea65594fe,119.0.6045.159-1
...deb,...,...,...,...
```

Or, in a CSV-viewer:

| file | size | size_cntrl | version | SHA256 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb | 103884100 | 15708 | 119.0.6045.159-1 | c409bb6cfb279c90fb516353b4728cbf97a71e8deb33dc3433cd503ea65594fe |
| ...deb | ... | ... | ... | ... |

---

**PS**: after check, if SHA256 ok, to install do it:

1. check the package name, with `dpkg-deb --info google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`
2. remove it `sudo dpkg -r google-chrome-stable`
3. install it, `sudo dpkg --install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`