# validate a deb package before trying to install it

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, deb

**TL;DR**
How do a verify that a deb file is complete and without error?

I have an incomplete download of a deb package that will error out on install.  Before trying to install it, I would like to check if it's valid.  As noted in [how-to-inspect-and-validate-a-deb-package-before-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642665/how-to-inspect-and-validate-a-deb-package-before-installation), I can use `dpkg-deb --info <deb file>` however this gives all the info but does not show any errors on my file.

In my particular case, I have the following file

```
# file is actually ~40MB, download the first 27MB
curl -r 0-28208916 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce-cli_20.10.21~3-0~ubuntu-jammy_amd64.deb
```

The following shows the info of the deb but does not report an incomplete file

```
dpkg-deb --info docker-ce-cli_20.10.21~3-0~ubuntu-jammy_amd64.deb
```

Output from dpkg-deb command,

```
 new Debian package, version 2.0.
 size 28208917 bytes: control archive=5436 bytes.
    1059 bytes,    24 lines      control
   14836 bytes,   195 lines      md5sums
 Package: docker-ce-cli
 Source: docker-ce
 Version: 5:20.10.21~3-0~ubuntu-jammy
 Architecture: amd64
 Maintainer: Docker <support@docker.com>
 Installed-Size: 145640
 Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34)
 Recommends: docker-scan-plugin
 Conflicts: docker (<< 1.5~), docker-engine, docker-engine-cs, docker.io, lxc-docker, lxc-docker-virtual-package
 Breaks: docker-ce (<< 5:0)
 Replaces: docker-ce (<< 5:0)
 Section: admin
 Priority: optional
 Homepage: https://www.docker.com
 Description: Docker CLI: the open-source application container engine
  Docker is a product for you to build, ship and run any application as a
  lightweight container
  .
  Docker containers are both hardware-agnostic and platform-agnostic. This means
  they can run anywhere, from your laptop to the largest cloud compute instance and
  everything in between - and they don't require you to use a particular
  language, framework or packaging system. That makes them great building blocks
  for deploying and scaling web apps, databases, and backend services without
  depending on a particular stack or provider.
```

Comment: A similar issue is discussed [here](
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/630910/sha1-verification-of-external-deb-package-before-install). It discusses checking the package checksum.

Comment: So what you're saying, is that there is no way to verify a package without using an external hash?